# Product of the first $N$ factorials

Tags: factorial, products

I'm trying to find a formula for the product of factorials:
$$\prod _{n=1}^{N}n!=\; ?$$
Now using a kind of "brute force", I believe that I can prove that $$\prod _{n=1}^{N}n!=\prod _{n=1}^{N}{n}^{N-n}$$
but I couldn't find a demonstration; I tried to use induction, but I only got  $$\left( N+1 \right) \prod _{n=1}^{N}{\frac {{n}^{N}}{{n}^{n}}}
$$

Comment: Considering the factorial operation is defined to concisely represent a product, I doubt there will be a nice expression. Can you explain what you've written at the end? I don't see how you've gone from an equation to just an expression.

Comment: @Peterix Note that this product admit a closed form in terms of a special function. More precisely, we have $$\prod_{n=1}^{N}n!=\prod_{n=1}^{N}\Gamma\left(n+1\right)=G\left(N+2\right)$$ where $G$ is the Barnes $G$ function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @ZevChonoles, we have

$$\prod_{n=1}^{N}n!=\prod_{n=1}^{N}n^{N-(n-1)} \tag 1$$

We can prove this by induction.  To that end, let's establish a base case.  For $N=2$, we have

$$\prod_{n=1}^{2}n!=(1!)\,(2!)=2$$

and

$$\prod_{n=1}^{2}n^{2-(n-1)} =(1^2)\,(2^1)=2$$

Now assume that $(1)$ is true for $N=K$.  Then, examine

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}n!&=(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K}n!\\\\
&=(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K}n^{K-(n-1)}\\\\
&=(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}n^{K-(n-1)}\\\\
&=(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}\frac{n^{(K+1)-(n-1)}}{n}\\\\
&=\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}n^{(K+1)-(n-1)}
\end{align}$$

and we're done!

Comment: I don't understand why $$(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K}n^{K-(n-1)}=(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}n^{K-(n-1)}$$

Comment: @peterix We can multiply by $1$ and not change the answer.  Put $K+1$ into the product and you get $1$.

Comment: Sorry if I keep asking but I don't get why $$(K+1)!\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}\frac{n^{(K+1)-(n-1)}}{n}=
\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}n^{(K+1)-(n-1)}$$

Comment: @Peterix $$\prod_{n=1}^{K+1}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{(1)(2)(3)\cdots (K+1)}=\frac{1}{(K+1)!}$$

Comment: right, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Peterix You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple demonstration, laid out pictorally:
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
N!\strut_\strut & 1 & 2 & \cdots & (N-1) & N\\
(N-1)!\strut_\strut & 1 & 2 & \cdots & (N-1)\\
\vdots\strut_\strut & \vdots& &{\cdot}^{\Large\cdot^{\huge\cdot}} \\
2!\strut_\strut & 1 & 2\\
1!\strut_\strut & 1\\\hline
\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^Nn! & 1^N & 2^{N-1} & \cdots & (N-1)^2 & N
\end{array}$$